error:cant find symbol in minecraft Modding (forge)
I making a mod to Minecraft 1.19 using Forge MDK (41.1.0). When im trying to create an item this appears:
error: cannot find symbol
     public static final DeferredRegister<Item> DORA = 
     DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.DORA, DarisCheat.MOD_ID);
                                                                                             
                                              ^
     symbol:   variable DORA
     location: class ForgeRegistries

This is my code:
package net.daris.cheat.item;

import net.minecraft.world.item.CreativeModeTab;
import net.minecraft.world.item.Item;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.EventBus;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.IEventBus;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.DeferredRegister;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistries;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.RegistryObject;

public class ModItems {
     public static final DeferredRegister<Item> DORA = DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.DORA,       DarisCheat.MOD_ID);

     public static void register(IEventBus eventBus){
        DORA.register(eventBus);
     }

     public static final RegistryObject<Item> DoraTop = DORA.register("doratop",
            ()->new Item(new Item.Properties().tab(CreativeModeTab.TAB_FOOD)));
}


[edit] your question and add the error and code directly. Additional inks are good for additional context but the question should be self-sufficient. Also note that your links are broken, which is why the questions should contain the more important information.

What does a "Cannot find symbol" or "Cannot resolve symbol" error mean?

Whops, i edited, how everything ok

There's no DORA constant in the ForgeRegistries class. Simple as that.
